# Error using Postman when trying to POST and GET

Tags: json, asp.net-core-mvc, postman

I want to post this JSON code  and send it to https://localhost:44324/api/ocorrenciasapi:

```
{
  "dispositivo":"dewdkij",
  "latitude" : "39",
  "longitude" : "-9",
  "azimute": "43",
  "fotografia": "lifhwee",
  "estado":"ldhel"
}
```

I doing this on the Body-raw with JSON. However, everytime I send this request, it returns "There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script:  SyntaxError: Unexpected token :". What should I do? 
The same happens when I do the GET request.

NOTE: I'm using a API Controller with action, using Entity Framework.

Comment: What's in the pre-request script?

Comment: I had the same code on the pre-request script, that was the problem. Thanks anyway